# Default value in text field, but only first time

Tags: javascript, php, html

I thought this should be pretty simple, but I just can't get my head around it.

I have a text field, which needs to be populated with a default value (number). So perhaps it should say "1" when it's loaded the first time.
But the user should be able to change it to any number - positiv, negativ or 0 and then save it.

A default value in the database is not a option, cause how the system is made up, and it may needs to be changeable in the furture, by other means than directly in the database.

How do I do that?

A elaboration is needed... :-)

It for a time schedule, where the user gets a certain time to do a phase. This time is made up of 2 "day number" fields. The second one the user can manipulate, if they know it can be done faster or slower. The second one is also the one that holds the default value. So perhaps they have 10 days, it can be 6 + 4, and then they can change the last one to any number negativ, positiv and zero. So the first time the page is loaded, the field should show the default value (4), and after that it should show that the user has inputted. The sum of the two fields, will in the end be calculated into the time schedule.
Maybe null is the best way

I've solved it by making the DB value NULL from the start as @nihiser suggested, end then the code like this: `value="<?php echo (is_null($res['r531e'])) ? 1 : $res['r531e']; ?>"` where 1 is the default value on that specific field.

But I wonder if it possible to do in the code only, so I don't have to use NULL in the database?

Comment: You will be storing the user's choice in the database ? It seems pretty straightforward, if the value is set then echo the value into the HTML otherwise echo your default value from the PHP.

Comment: I just editede the post, I forgot it should also save 0. If I just check for if is set, and if the DB value is 0, is will post 2 but should post 0

Comment: By which terms do you detect that "first time"? How does your script detect that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried :

```
<input type='text' value='1' />
```

It should do the work...

Comment: And want will that show, if the user changes the value to say 5 and reload the page?

Answer (score 0):

let say you have fetched the value from database in $value variable 
then you can use ternary operator to display the value

```
<input type='text' value="<?php echo (!empty($value) || $value==0) ? $value : 1 ?>" />
//Put your Default value instead of 1.
```

Comment: I tried that, problem is if the user changes the value to 0, when the page is reloaded it will show the default value instead of 0.

Comment: I have updated the answer just check if it is working for you or not...

Comment: Nope it didn't help. Maybe having null as starting value in the database is the best way as @nihiser suggested. If its null, I can check for that the first time, and after that I can assume the user made a choice, either to keep the default value or to change it, and then it should contain a value.

Comment: can i know the exact problem you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type='text' value="<?php echo isset($value) ? $value : 1; ?>" />
```

You need to have a default value if the value isn't set in the database. If you query the value and set it in the $value variable, it will only be set if the record exists thus a ternary with the isset function will only be true if the record is found. Therefor if there is no record the value will be 1. Once the form is submitted the value will be set.

Comment: How does this check for the condition "but only first time"?

Comment: While this code may solve the OP's issue, it is better to add context, or an explanation as to why this solves the OP's problem, so future visitors can learn from your post, and apply this knowledge to their own issues. High Quality Answers are much more likely to be upvoted, and contribute to the value and quality of SO as a platform. You can also add a link to documentation, if that helps.